# Automatically set attribute after constructor per annotation

Tags: java, constructor, annotations

i have a class. Something like this:

```
public class Example {
  public Example() {
    System.out.println("Constructor");
  }
}
```

Now i want to have an attribute "Version" which is given automatically after construction. Is it possible to resolve it per annotation? The best solution would be, if i could write a annotation like @VersionControl above some classes and then another module sets an attribute "version" for the classes.

Something like this:

```
@VersionControl
public class Example {

  int version; //this should be set automatically

  public Example() {
    System.out.println("Constructor");
  }
}
```

Is it possible? Thx for your help!

Comment: Sure. Have a look at AspectJ or libraries that allow bytecode rewriting. But as it stands now, your question is very broad and probably not very suitable for SO.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will have a look at AspectJ and try to answer my question by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution with annotation and aspectj:

Annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
   public @interface MyAnnotation{
}
```

Aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {

  @Pointcut("execution((@MyAnnotation *).new(..))")
   public void bla() {
   }

  @After("bla()")
   public void after(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    try {
     joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getDeclaredField("version").set(joinPoint.getTarget(), VersionProvider.getVersion());
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Example object:

```
@MyAnnotation
public class Example {

 public long version;

 public long getDarwinVersion() {
    return version;
 }

}
```

In this solution, the version will be set after the constructor of the annotated class was called.